# How to set COMPILE_DEFINITIONS through cmake command line

Tags: cmake, compilation, c-preprocessor, cross-compiling

I am building a couple of 3rd party libraries for integration.

There are two different source codes for two libs, libA and libB.
The libA has following, in its CMakeLists.txt

```
    project(libA)
...
    add_library(${PROJECT} ${SRCS})
    target_link_library(${PROJECT} DOESNOTMATTER)
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC LETS_USE_GORILLA)
```

libA compilation is successful separately as shared lib.

libB is dependent on libA.

While compiling libB, it is expected that [public compile definition](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) of libA are automatically taken care by cmake to be available in libB. But they are not.

Now, if I add below **target_compile_definitions** in CMakeLists.txt of libB, it compiles successfully.

```
    project(libB)
...
    add_library(${PROJECT} ${SRCS})
    target_link_library(${PROJECT} libA)
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC LETS_USE_GORILLA)
```

But, as this is a 3rd party code, I am not allowed to change the CMakeLists.txt.

**Question** - How can I pass some arguments in cmake command line  to change the [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)

Comment: You cannot change COMPILE_DEFINITIONS property from command line, you need to modify the code. "While compiling libB, it is expected that public compile definition of libA are automatically taken care by cmake to be available in libB." - These are good expectations of libB, assuming it links with the **target** `libA`. (Only CMake target can carry out PUBLIC properties like compile definitions). So it seems you have **manually changed** something in libB project, so it is not work as expected, haven't you?

Comment: No, Have not changed anything in both libA and libB. The owners of the 3rd party libraries commented that if I build A and B separately, I need to pass the compile definitions separately. Thus, was looking for ways to pass it through command line without changing the code.